# How can I create a function to detect missing data denotes as '-999' and to replace it with average data adjacent to missing data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd


    case= {'row1': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'row2': [-999,-999,-999,-999,-999],
        'row3': [1,2,-999,4,5],
        'row4': [-999,2,3,4,5],
        'row5': [1,2,3,4,-999],
        'row6': [1,2,-999,-999,5],
        'row7': [-999,-999,3,4,5],
        'row8': [1,2,3,-999,-999]
        }





     df = pd.DataFrame(case, columns = 
     ['row_1','row_2','row_3','row_4','row_5','row_6','row_7','row_8'])

     df = df.replace([-999],[np.nan])
     df = df.fillna(df.mean())



     print (df)
```

This is my code and I would like to also replace "row 2" with adjacent data which has a valid value since average cannot be compute as such.

Comment: What do you mean by *adjacent data*? also I think your question should be edited to just `df = pd.DataFrame(case)` instead of `df = pd.DataFrame(case, columns = 
     ['row_1','row_2','row_3','row_4','row_5','row_6','row_7','row_8'])` ?

Comment: I believe question is asking to replace those missing data in column row 2 with row 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you called *fillna*, call *interpolate* with *axis=1*, i.e. fill
any remaining *NaN* values with just mean value of adjacent columns.

You can do the whole job in a **single** instruction:

```
df = df.fillna(df.mean()).interpolate(axis=1)
```

The result, for your source data sample is:

```
   row1  row2  row3  row4  row5      row6  row7  row8
0   1.0   1.0   1.0   3.5   1.0  1.000000   4.0   1.0
1   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0  2.000000   4.0   2.0
2   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0  2.666667   3.0   3.0
3   4.0   4.0   4.0   4.0   4.0  2.666667   4.0   2.0
4   5.0   5.0   5.0   5.0   2.5  5.000000   5.0   2.0
```

Comment: Hi. Appreciate your advice. I have tried using df = df.fillna(method='ffill',axis=1) instead and it solved the issue as well.  However, yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the code very well.
You just need to drop the 'columns=....' in the pd.DataFrame. It should be like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(case)
```

Then if you want to replace remaining null with the row average:

```
df = df.fillna(df.mean(axis=1), axis=1)
```

Comment: The `axis=1` parameter in `fillna` is useless with scalars, this is only used when filling with previous/next values